# Which is correct, Routes to circumnavigate or Routes circumnavigating?

Tags: grammar

> 1. These were the spice routes to circumnavigate the globe.
> 2. These were the spice routes circumnavigating the globe.

Which of the two is correct?  I think sentence (2) is correct.   Could you help me clarify it?

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct, but the emphasis is different. The first is about **people** circumnavigating the globe, and the routes permit them to do it. The second is about **routes** that circumnavigate the globe, regardless of whether anybody uses these routes.

Givan that you are talking about spice routes, which is a particular kind of route, the latter is the most appropriate option.